# pass data from dialog to react function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dialog, parameter-passing

I have a MUI custom dialog, with 1 input text and 2 action buttons (Cancel, Done).
I can pass onClick function etc.. but
I have problem in passing data from this dialog to the actual parent widget, because when I click on "Done" i need to:

- save the text
- close the dialog

**My Dialog**

```
 const FormDialog = ({ open, onClose, onSave }) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    const parentToChild = () => {};

  if (!open) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={onClose}>
        <DialogTitle>Edit</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>Add name</DialogContentText>
          <TextField
            value={value}
            onChange={setValue(value)} />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={onClose}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={() => onSave(value)}>Salva</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
```

**and the dialog inside my class:**
This is where I should receive the text value

```
    <FormDialog open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)} onSave={() => editCategory()} />

const editCategory = (value) => () => {
    console.log(value);
    setOpen(false);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to receive the parameter in the onSave parent function

```
//Before
... onSave={()=>editCategory()}
//After
... onSave={(value)=>editCategory(value)}
```

But that is not needed since you can pass the function editCategory directly to onSave (editCategory already receives "value"):

```
... onSave={editCategory}
```

**IMPORTANT**

```
// wrong
const editCategory = (value) => () => {...} 

// correct
const editCategory = (value) => {...}
```

**So, finally:**

```
<FormDialog open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)} onSave={editCategory} />
const editCategory = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    setOpen(false);
};
```

Comment: oh nice. Thanks a lot! . However, "if (!open) return {null}; " gives me error saying that it's missing " : "

Comment: Glad I could help!
Ignore the {null} thing. Apparently it's outdated (2017). I'm removing that from my answer
Thanks for the +15

Comment: Thanks to you! Passing properties, function between class it's the harder thing in coding!!!

Comment: A bit. Just remember that there are multiple ways to do things. I suggest you dig more into the differences and equivalences between Component Classes and Functional Components